# Straight edges for oblique shape in Adobe CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I need to draw oblique shapes in Ai CC, when I use Rectangle tool, then Transform it, edges become pixelated. And those become unclear after saving it as image. Can anyone prompt better way to draw shapes? :(

Want to achive the result something like this shape https://gyazo.com/c67f3987bba6a465d7fd4f3771e9ecc4

my shape is this 
https://gyazo.com/a6f27c35b07c81b488d6e3eeb65cc611

in PIXEL PREVIEW mode it's like this
https://gyazo.com/15ff67282cd51479f94bed5af749a3b5

Comment: How big is the object you're drawing? (Select your object, then go to Window > Info to see the width and height). I suspect the object you're drawing is really tiny.

Comment: I need 24px width and 21px height shape, as it is. Yes it's very small. but the first image I show you (close icon) is small too, but it looks good

Comment: Your first image is a preview of a shape in Illustrator, still in vector form. When you save as an image (like jpg or png), your vectors are "rasterized", which is why you see the pixels instead of smooth lines in the last image. What you are seeing is expected for a small, rasterized image.

Comment: Thanks for answers, but is there a way to escape from this? in other words hide that transparent pixels which add blurity to the image.I know that it's almost impossible, just to reduce that unclear effect

Comment: Check out some of these existing answers for creating small art that is more crisp: [making crisp buttons](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10615/ios-image-for-buttons-not-crisp/10617#10617), [reduce aliasing on icons](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28870/how-can-i-reduce-the-aliasing-that-occurs-around-my-custom-icon-web-font-when-it), [working on small resolution images](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6442/working-on-small-resolution-images-in-photoshop-icons/6445#6445). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This helped me much. I do such job first time and couldn't search it as needed.